# Multiple rsync versions conflict

Tags: macos, rsync

RSYNC only fails when I try to sync extended attributes (Mac OS X) with the following error.

```
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at io.c(599) [sender=3.1.0]
rsync: [receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

As far as I know, rsync requires the destination server to also have rsync installed. I guess this problem is happening because I issue this command with a recent version (3.1) while the remote server is a Mac with two versions, the system default being 2.6.9.

How can I make sure that my rsync command uses the right remote rsync version?

Comment: Run your copy from the system with the older version of rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some background: version 2 of the rsync protocol doesn't support extended file metadata. Apple added a sort of hack to their version of rsync, that sends extended metadata as pseudo-files in AppleDouble format -- i.e. for file.txt it'd sync the file's contents as "file.txt" and its metadata as the pseudo-file "._file.txt". Version 3 of the rsync protocol added native support for extended metadata, but of course this is completely incompatible with version 2.

Fortunately, the solution is simple provided you know where a compatible version of rsync is installed on the remote computer: use the `--rsync-path=` option to specify where to find the compatible remote. For example, if rsync version 3 is installed at /usr/local/bin/rsync3 on both the local and remote computers, you'd use something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync3 -aNHX --fileflags --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync3 -e ssh ...etc...
```

Comment: If you don't have control over the issued command and thus can't rewrite it to an absolute path, here's my solution involving a custom login shell script: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392489/77613